# Getting the first object that satisfies condition

Tags: java, guava

I have a problem with downloading the first object in the list that meets the condition.

My code always returns the first object that is on the list, regardless of condition. Returns the person with id = 1.

```
main(){
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Person> persons = Lists.newArrayList();
    persons.add(new Person("1", "aaa",23, true));
    persons.add(new Person("2", "bbb",16, false));
    persons.add(new Person("3", "ccc",56, true));


    Person per = (Person) Iterables.getFirst(persons, new Predicate<Person>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Person person) {
            return person.getAge()> 50;
        }
    });

    System.out.println(per.getId());  // always "1"
}


public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean isSome;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public boolean isSome() {
        return isSome;
    }

    public void setSome(boolean isPaid) {
        this.isSome = isPaid;
    }
    public Person(){}

    public Person(String id, String name, int age, boolean isSome){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.isSome = isSome;
    }
}
```

Could someone explain why this is happening and how to deal with it?

Comment: What does the code for the `Person` class look like? It doesn't seem like the issue is in the code you posted.

Comment: The fact that you're casting the result of `getFirst` to `Person` is a tip-off. You're having to cast because the method can't be inferred to return `Person` since you're trying to return a `Predicate<Person>` as the default value. And of course if your list were empty, this code would produce a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Iterables.getFirst()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getFirst(java.lang.Iterable,%20T)) doesn't do what you think it does. You should be using [`Iterables.tryFind()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#tryFind(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)) method, which returns the first matching element in the iterable passed. It returns an `Optional<T>`, so you need to invoke `get()` on the result, or `Optional#or()`, if you want some default value.

```
Person per = Iterables.tryFind(persons, new Predicate<Person>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Person person) {
            return person.getAge()> 50;
        }
    }).or(defaultPerson);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Iterables.getFirst` returns the first element of the first argument e.g. the first element of persons. The second parameter is the default value in case `persons` is empty. You could use `filter` instead:

```
Person person = Iterables.getFirst(Iterables.filter(persons, new Predicate<Person>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Person person) {
        return person.getAge() > 50;
    }
}), null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Though you are attempting to solve this using guava you might be interested in how this can be done in java8:

```
    List<Person> persons = Lists.newArrayList();
    persons.add(new Person("1", "aaa",23, true));
    persons.add(new Person("2", "bbb",16, false));
    persons.add(new Person("3", "ccc",56, true));

    Person per = persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getAge() > 50).findFirst().get();

    System.out.println(per.getId());
```

findFirst will return an `Optional<Person>` for the sake of brevity I called get on it, but be aware that get will return null should nothing match the predicate of `getAge > 50`

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. The OP is having a specific problem with their code and asking what's wrong with it and how to fix it.

Comment: The question was 'Getting the first object that satisfies condition' this answers that question, admittedly using a different method than they have started trying. I will update my answer to be more explicit that this is an alternative, not a fix of their current implementation

Comment: The question is "why this behavior happens with this code and how to deal with this behavior", plus the OP never stated using Java 8 anywhere.